# перегрузка операторов << и >> для записи/считывания в/из бинарный файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно перегрузить в классе операторы << и >> для записи/считывания в/из бинарный файл. Я написал так:

```
ifstream& operator >> (ifstream &s, int &obj)
{
    s.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(int));
    return s;
}
ofstream& operator << (ofstream &s, int &obj)
{
    s.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(int));
    return s;
}
```

Теперь, в методах моего класса я пишу вместо этого:

```
write((char*)&obj, sizeof(Type));
```

вот это:

```
(*this) << obj;
```

Но теперь ввод данных перестал работать корректно, и я не могу понять почему. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Э... А зачем вы перекрыли чтение и запись целых чисел, а не вашего типа?..

Comment: В чем проявляется некорректность вывода?

Comment: Более подробно распишите то, что у Вас не работает

Comment: в файл попадает не значение, а адрес переменной.

Comment: `operator <<` и иже с ним _предназначены_ для текстового, не для бинарного ввода/вывода. Хотя технически вы _можете_ переопределить их, это всё равно что использовать функцию `to_string` для коммита транзакции в базе данных.

Comment: Просто мне нужно перегрузить для инта и для сложного типа, в файле же сложный тип и инт разное количество байт занимают.

Comment: Вы хотите по-байтовое чтение и запись, и чтобы размеры блоков для чтения и записи соответсвовали объектам к которым вы применяете операторы `<<` и `>>`?

Comment: @Cerbo да, именно так

Comment: @zof А что означает this в этой конструкции (*this) << obj;? Ведь левым операндом должен пыть объект потока, не так ли?

Comment: Распишите это подробнее в вопросе с примерами: какие байты в файле какие у объекта. И получится отличный вопрос с хорошим рейтингом :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я реализую сложную структуру данных в бинарном файле и мой класс производный от fstream. В конструкторе этого дерева создаётся файл, поэтому и this использую

Comment: @VladD "operator << и иже с ним предназначены для текстового, не для бинарного ввода/вывода. " - я нигде не видел подобного ограничения.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151840/why-cant-i-read-fstreams-binary-data-with-operator, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ - особо внимательно секцию для целых типов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как писали выше, эти операторы рассчитаны на работу с текстовыми файлами с разделителями (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151840/why-cant-i-read-fstreams-binary-data-with-operator, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). Т.е. переопределять их не есть хорошо для такого использования. Но можно сделать класс-обёртку и для него определить их поведение, примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename ios>
struct binary_ios
{
    binary_ios(ios &stream) : stream(stream) {}
    ios &stream;
};

template<typename ios>
binary_ios<ios> make_binary_iostream(ios &stream)
{
    return std::move(binary_ios<ios>(stream));
}

template<typename ios, typename T>
binary_ios<ios>& operator>>(binary_ios<ios> &io, T &value)
{
    io.stream.read((char*)&value, sizeof(T));
    return io;
}

template<typename ios, typename T>
binary_ios<ios>& operator<<(binary_ios<ios> &io, const T& value)
{
    io.stream.write((const char*)&value, sizeof(T));
    return io;
}

int main() 
{
    auto bcin  = make_binary_iostream(cin);
    auto bcout = make_binary_iostream(cout);

    struct Foo
    {
        uint8_t sync;
        uint32_t payload;
    } __attribute__((packed));

    bcout << (char)57;
    bcout << (uint32_t)31337;
    bcout << (uint64_t)31338;
    bcout << (char)56;

    Foo data = {0x47, 0xdeadbeef};
    bcout << data << data << data;

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код выедет примерно такое:

```
$ ./a.out 
9izjz8Gﾭ�Gﾭ�Gﾭh
```

Или, через hexdump:

```
$ ./a.out | hexdump -C
00000000  39 69 7a 00 00 6a 7a 00  00 00 00 00 00 38 47 ef  |9iz..jz......8G.|
00000010  be ad de 47 ef be ad de  47 ef be ad de           |...G....G....|
0000001d
```

Во первых - ожидаемое количество байт, во вторых - ожидаемые значения. Для чисел явно указываю тип: иначе есть вероятность на другой машине не прочитать. Можно добавить ещё атрибут для указания endianess файла и делать конвертации на чтении/записи. Ну и вместо шаблонных операторов лучше определить нешаблонные, что бы всё подряд не вышло засунуть.

Comment: Я побаловался с этим переопределением `<< и >>` и чтобы все заработало, надо было использовать  не `ifstream/ofstream`, а `fstream`.